# Dom4j selectNodes(arg) don't give list of nodes

Tags: java, xml-namespaces, dom4j

I am using DOM4j for XML work in java, 
my xml is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<abcd name="ab.catalog" xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/pqr" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xyz.com/pqr ./abc.xyz.xsd">             
<efg>
......
</efg>
<efg>
.....
</efg>
</abcd>
```

then,

```
List<Node>list = document.selectNodes("/abcd/efg");
```

gets the size of list zero. I feel it's due to namespace specified in the xml.
I tried a lot but cn't get success.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unprefixed element names in XPath expressions refer to elements that are not in a namespace - they do not take account of the "default" `xmlns="..."` namespace declared on the document.  You need to declare a prefix for the namespace in the XPath engine and then use that prefix in the expression.  Here is an example inspired by [the DOM4J javadocs](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/XPath.html#setNamespaceURIs(java.util.Map)):

```
Map uris = new HashMap();
uris.put("pqr", "http://www.xyz.com/pqr");
XPath xpath = document.createXPath("/pqr:abcd/pqr:efg");
xpath.setNamespaceURIs(uris);
List<Node> nodes = xpath.selectNodes(document);
```

Comment: @ Ian: thanxs, it works, but i have a query if i have to retrieve some more node or node value in the child to child node, then i tried as the same specified above like                                           >        for(Node node:nodes){
    XPath xpath1 = document.createXPath("//edx:Name/value-");
   xpath1.setNamespaceURIs(uris);
    Node nameNode = (Node) xpath1.selectSingleNode(node);
 }                                                                    but it gives nameNode null. how to make it workable like dom4j. any input will be appreciable.

Comment: @user1808932 `//edx:Name/value-` is an _absolute_ path, which will start looking from the root node of the document that contains `node`.  If you want `edx:Name` descendants of the current `node` then you need to use a relative path `.//edx:Name/value-` (with a leading dot).

Answer (score -5):

Modify your code :

```
List<Node>list = document.selectNodes("//abcd/efg");
```

Comment: this is not true.  the `//` syntax has nothing to do with namespaces

Comment: This answer is utterly wrong and should be deleted.